# Mongodb query - and condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I did this query `http://server/usuarios?query={"senha":"1234"}` and works fine: it lists all `usuarios` with `senha: 1234`

Now I need to query all `usuarios` with `senha: 1234` and `email: igor@teste`. I tried: `http://server/usuarios?query={$and[{"senha":"1234"}, {"email":"igor@teste"}]}` but I got error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
http://server/usuarios?query={"$and" : [{"senha":"1234"}, {"email":"igor@teste"}]}
```

Comment: @Chucrutes much simpler and the same thing. The "and" is always implied within the same document in MongoDB queries: `http://server/usuarios?query={"senha":"1234", "email":"igor@teste"}`